# When connection with Mailkit, does `SecureSocketOptions.StartTlsWhenAvailable` cover TLS verification?

Tags: .net-core, mailkit, mimekit

I notice that `Mailkit.SMTPCLient` can connect with various TLS options as well as containing a `ServerCertificateValidationCallback` -- Does this callback mean there are additional steps that should be taken to verify the TLS certificate? or will `SecureSocketOptions.StartTls` and `SecureSocketOptions.StartTlsWhenAvailable` handle the certificate work without that callback if I pass one of them as the last arg to `.Connect` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ServerCertificateValidationCallback` is passed to the underlying `SslStream` and will be called if/when the `SslStream` initiates an SSL handshake.

All of the `SecureSocketOptions` enum values will trigger an SSL handshake except `None` and potentially `StartTlsWhenAvailable`.

`StartTlsWhenAvailable` detects whether or not the SMTP, IMAP, or POP3 server supports the STARTTLS extension, and, if it does, will upgrade the connection to a TLS connection.